# Bootstrap method with 2 Fisher matrices in order to do the cross-correlations between both

Tags: variance, bootstrap, covariance-matrix, cross-correlation, fisher-information

I have 2 Fisher matrices where each colum/row represents the information (in Fisher's sense) of astrophysical parameters. These parameters are in the same order for both matrices.

Now, I would like to perform a synthesis of these 2 matrices in order to get and extract all the informations on these parameters.

For this, I tried to use the "Bootstrap method" where I resample a lot of times to get the variances of the inverse of final Fisher matrix, i.e the final covariance matrix ( diagonal elements of this final covariance matrix are the variances whereas off-diagonals elements represent the covariances).

I have implemented that with the following script ( F1.txt and F2.txt are the concerned matrices ) :

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np

def load_matrix(path):
    """Charge une matrice à partir d'un fichier texte."""
    return np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=' ')

def calculate_F_final(A, B):
    """Calcule la matrice finale F à partir des matrices A et B."""
    # Cet exemple utilise simplement A + B comme placeholder.
    # Remplacez cette opération par votre calcul spécifique de F_final.
    return A + B

def calculate_F_initial(A, B):
    """Calcule la matrice de Fisher initiale à partir des matrices A et B.
       Remplacez cette fonction par votre calcul réel."""
    # Exemple : retourne simplement A + B comme placeholder.
    return A + B

def bootstrap_F_final(A, B, n_bootstrap=1000):
    """Effectue le bootstrap sur les matrices A et B pour estimer la variance de F_final."""
    n = A.shape[0]
    F_bootstrap = np.zeros((n_bootstrap, n, n))
    
    for i in range(n_bootstrap):
        # Exemple simple de bootstrap: rééchantillonnage avec remplacement des lignes de A et B
        indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(n), size=n, replace=True)
        A_resampled = A[indices, :]
        B_resampled = B[indices, :]
        
        F_resampled = calculate_F_final(A_resampled, B_resampled)
        F_bootstrap[i] = F_resampled
    
    # Calcul de la variance pour chaque élément de F à travers les répliques bootstrap
    var_F = np.var(F_bootstrap, axis=0)
    return var_F

# Charger les matrices A et B
A = load_matrix("F1.txt")
B = load_matrix("F2.txt")

# Calculer la matrice de Fisher initiale
F_initial = calculate_F_initial(A, B)

# Bootstrap pour estimer la variance de F_final
var_F = bootstrap_F_final(A, B, n_bootstrap=100000)

# Utiliser var_F pour analyses ultérieures, comme la construction d'une matrice de covariance
print('var_F = ', var_F)

# Construction de la matrice de Fisher finale avec régularisation
lambda_reg = 1e-10  # Ajustez cette valeur selon les besoins
diagonal_adjustment = np.sqrt(np.diag(var_F)) + lambda_reg
F_final = F_initial + np.diag(diagonal_adjustment)

# Inverser la matrice de Fisher finale pour obtenir la matrice de covariance
F_final_inverse = np.linalg.inv(F_final)

# Sauvegarder la matrice de Fisher finale et son inverse
np.savetxt('F_final.txt', F_final)
np.savetxt('F_final_inverse.txt', F_final_inverse)

# Remplacer la commande suivante par la manière dont vous utilisez printFoM dans votre environnement
os.system('printFoM F_final.txt OPT GCph 0 0 F N')
```

the binary `printFoM` shows the constraints on fiducials where we invert the final Fisher matrix.

From your point of view, do you think the "`Bootstrap method`" is correctly implemented ?     #

Espcially, about these 3 lines :

```
lambda_reg = 1e-10  # Ajustez cette valeur selon les besoins
diagonal_adjustment = np.sqrt(np.diag(var_F)) + lambda_reg
F_final = F_initial + np.diag(diagonal_adjustment)
```

I am not sure this is the right method. Indeed, the results for constraints (very small variances got) here are too nice to be true, I have doubts. If soemone could help me to confirm the validity of the "Bootstrap method" coded here.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "variance of the Fisher matrix" and by "all the information" about the parameters?

Comment: @whuber . Sorry, I have changed the formulation : by variance of the Fisher matrix, I meant the variances present in the diagonal of the inverse of Fisher matrix which is the covariance matrix). And secondly, "all the information" about the parameters is the information in Fisher's sense (more the information is high, more the constraints, i.e variances are small). Regards

Comment: Are you asking, then, how to combine the standard errors of two independent parameter estimates?

Comment: yes, I know that with MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimator), we get 1/sigma^2 = 1/sigma_1^2 + 1/sigma_2^2 , but I have difficulties to translate it with Fisher matrices